# Shopify - can i use a reusable variable list in settings_schema.json?

Tags: json, themes, shopify, liquid

I would like to create a variable for a list of select options that can be re-used for multiple settings. example (variable state_list in the code below)...

`{
    "name": "Shop page",
    "settings": [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "content": "State"
        },
        {
            "type": "select",
            "id": "state_select",
            "label": "Choose State...",
            "options": state_list,
            "default": "Alabama",
            "info": "info text here"
       }
    ]
}`

and then (obviously) somewhere else, define that list. something like this...

`var state_list = [
    {
        "group": "states",
        "value": "AL",
        "label": "Alabama"
    },
    {
        "group": "states",
        "value": "AK",
        "label": "Alaska"
    },
    {
        "group": "states",
        "value": "AZ",
        "label": "Arizona"
    }
    etc.
]`

please - someone tell me this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in the schema object.

The schema objects accepts only JSON syntax and you can't pass any liquid variables in it.

This applies for the `settings_schema.json` file and the `{% schema %}` section.

You can't pass any liquid object, translatable strings or anything other piece of data that is not static text (a.k.a JSON object).

So if you are trying to do the following, it's **INVALID**:

```
{
    "type": "select",
    "id": "select",
    "label": "Select",
    "options": [
        {{ select_options }}
    ],
    "default": "option"
}
```